# Failing to accumulate compile time constants

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I am trying to create a variadic `int` argument vectors and perform `+` operators on them.

For example:

```
vec<1,2,3> v1;
vec<4,5>   v2;
auto res = v1+v2;
res.print(); // should print 5 7 3 vec<5,7,3> is the result.
```

And now I want to create struct `vecSum`, which will sum up the vectors given to it;

```
namespace ex {

    template<int... N>
    struct vec
    {
        static const int size = sizeof...(N);
        void print() {
            ((std::cout << N << " "), ...);
        }
    };

    template<int...N, int...M, int ...S>
    auto add(vec<N...>, vec<M...>, std::index_sequence<S...>) {
        constexpr int arr1[sizeof...(S)]{ N... };
        constexpr int arr2[sizeof...(S)]{ M... };
        return vec<(arr1[S] + arr2[S])...>{};
    }

    template<int...N, int...M>
    auto operator+(vec<N...> v1, vec<M...> v2) {
        constexpr size_t size = std::max(sizeof...(N), sizeof...(M));
        return add(v1, v2, std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto all(Args... args) { return (... + args); }

    template<typename... Ts>
    struct vecSum
    {
        static constexpr auto res = all(Ts);
    };
}
```

This test works fine:

```
ex::vec<1, 2, 3> v1;
ex::vec<4, 5> v2;
ex::vec<2> v3;
auto r = ex::all(v1,v2,v3);
r.print();

This prints 7 7 3;
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
vecSum<vec<1,3,4>, vec<3>, vec<3,4,5>> z;
z::res.print(); and I expect 7 7 9
```

Instead I have this error:

```
error C2275: 'Ts': illegal use of this type as an expression
error C2119: 'res': the type for 'auto' cannot be deduced from an empty initializer
```

Can someone please hint what's wrong here? I know I am trying to pass types parameter pack `Ts` as expression, is there a workaround or fix for this?

Comment: Your working code doesn't appear to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/M3W6eT). Please make a [mre]

Comment: did you forget a typedef in the declaration of z?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see some little problems in your code...

---

1. **expand `Ts`**

In `vecSum` you define `res` as follows

```
static constexpr auto res = all(Ts);
```

You have to expand `Ts` as follows

```
// ...............................VVVVV
static constexpr auto res = all(Ts{}...);
```

---

2. **`std::index_sequence` contains `std::size_t`, not `int`, values**

Your `add()` is defined as follows

```
template<int...N, int...M, int ...S>
auto add(vec<N...>, vec<M...>, std::index_sequence<S...>)
```

But the `S...` values are `std::size_t`

```
// ........................VVVVVVVVVVV
template<int...N, int...M, std::size_t ...S>
auto add(vec<N...>, vec<M...>, std::index_sequence<S...>)
```

or template deduction doesn't works.

---

3. **`constexpr` functions**

If `vecSum` has to be `constexpr`, you have to define all necessary functions (`add()`, `all()`, `operator+()`) as `constexpr`.

---

4. **`print() const`**

The method `vec::print()` is better `const`, given that you want print a `constexpr` `vecSum::res` value.

---

The following is a full compiling corrected example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace ex {

    template<int... N>
    struct vec
    {
        static const int size = sizeof...(N);
        void print() const {
            ((std::cout << N << " "), ...);
        }
    };

    template<int...N, int...M, std::size_t ...S>
    constexpr auto add(vec<N...>, vec<M...>, std::index_sequence<S...>) {
        constexpr int arr1[sizeof...(S)]{ N... };
        constexpr int arr2[sizeof...(S)]{ M... };
        return vec<(arr1[S] + arr2[S])...>{};
    }

    template<int...N, int...M>
    constexpr auto operator+(vec<N...> v1, vec<M...> v2) {
        constexpr size_t size = std::max(sizeof...(N), sizeof...(M));
        return add(v1, v2, std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr auto all(Args... args) { return (... + args); }

    template<typename... Ts>
    struct vecSum
    {
        static constexpr auto res = all(Ts{}...);
    };
}

int main ()
 { 

   ex::vecSum<ex::vec<1,3,4>, ex::vec<3>, ex::vec<3,4,5>> z;
   z.res.print();
 }
```